# Fetch the newest row grouped by a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, query-refactor

My problem seems like it should have a much simpler solution than what I have come up with. Starting with this data set:

**log_table**

```
+--------+-----------+------------------+---------+
| log_id | entity_id |       date       | comment |
+--------+-----------+------------------+---------+
|      1 | A         | 2012-10-23 07:50 | foo     |
|      2 | B         | 2012-10-23 07:59 | bar     |
|      3 | B         | 2012-10-23 08:11 | baz     |
|      4 | A         | 2012-10-23 08:23 | bat     |
+--------+-----------+------------------+---------+
```

Say I wanted to get the *latest* date of log entries for each entity so that the result looked like:

```
Results:
+-----------+------------------+--------------+
| entity_id |  last_log_date   | last_comment |
+-----------+------------------+--------------+
| B         | 2012-10-23 08:11 | baz          |
| A         | 2012-10-23 08:23 | bat          |
+-----------+------------------+--------------+
```

I'm currently using MySQL that looks something like:

```
SELECT
  `entity_id`,
  `date` AS last_log_date,
  `comment` AS last_comment
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM `log_table`
  ORDER BY `date` DESC, log_id ASC
) AS `ordered_log`
GROUP BY `entity_id`
```

This works fine but it doesn't seem very efficient to me, there *has* to be a better way of doing this, surely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a Subquery that Gathers Keys from the the `log_table` with Maximum Date Per Entity. Then, perform an INNER JOIN of that Subquery back to the `log_table`.

```
SELECT
    B.entity_id,B.last_log_date,B.last_comment
FROM
(
    SELECT entity_id,MAX(last_log_date) last_log_date
    FROM log_table GROUP BY entity_id
) A INNER JOIN B USING (entity_id,last_log_date);
```

Give it a Try !!!

You can really speed this up if you have a compound index like this

```
ALTER TABLE log_table ADD INDEX entity_date_ndx (entity_id,last_log_date);
```

Indexes on each separate column may yield index merges. This compound index will bypass that.

Please try `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT
    B.entity_id,B.last_log_date,B.last_comment
FROM
(
    SELECT entity_id,MAX(last_log_date) last_log_date
    FROM log_table GROUP BY entity_id
) A LEFT JOIN B USING (entity_id,last_log_date);
```

Comment: Ok this query seems to be more efficient. On a table with 87,283 distinct entity_id and 1,309,252 records, _my_ query takes too long (more than 50s until I killed the query) but _your_ query takes just over 11 seconds. Is there a way to speed this up further? I have indexes on the `entity_id` and the `date` columns already.

Ideally the query should run more or less instantly if possible...

Comment: @Asgrim Do you have two separate indexes on the `entity_id` and `date` columns, or one index across both columns?

Comment: @matts As per @RolandoMySQLDBA's edited answer I added a compound index to the columns and this didn't make any difference. Running just the subquery itself (i.e. the `SELECT entity_id,MAX(last_log_date) last_log_date FROM log_table GROUP BY entity_id` part) and that is what is taking the time to run (it still takes 11 seconds). It seems to me that this isn't going to get any quicker?

Comment: Please change the INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN to see it ordering of subquery is preserved and faster.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA That does improve it slightly, but running _only_ the subquery (i.e. `SELECT entity_id, MAX(\`date\`) last_log_date FROM log_table GROUP BY entity_id`) is taking 8 seconds on its own. What I asked in my last comment is if there is a way to vastly increase the performance of just that query - that would most likely solve all the issues...

Comment: The issues stem from the comment field being a TEXT type. I imagine this causes a large amount of disk seek type in such a large table (1.3 million rows), so I have done this a different way. I have accepted your answer, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3):

The subquery works; here's how you would do it without a subquery:

```
SELECT
  `entity_id`,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(`date` ORDER BY `date` DESC), ',', 1) AS last_log_date,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(`comment` ORDER BY `date` DESC), ',', 1) AS last_comment
FROM `log_table`
GROUP BY `entity_id`
```

The query above uses `GROUP_CONCAT` to generate a long concatenation of values per group, which is then parsed to extract first token via `SUBSTRING_INDEX`.

You could have an excellent way of solving it if only MySQL supported Window Functions (aka Analytic Functions). It does, not , and we are left with hacks around `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: Thanks - a different answer that also worked, but was just as slow as the other.. it seems a bit hackier too, but nice thinking :)

Comment: What keys do you have on that table? a KEY(entity_id, `date`) should do well for my query.

Comment: As I described in the comments in @RolandoMySQLDBA's answer, adding a compound key didn't make any difference. The issue in the end was the huge amount of data in the TEXT field in the comment column meaning there was too much disk seeking going on. I preferred the subquery to using a GROUP_CONCAT hack, that's all.